# Heading and links not showing in Global Navigation

Tags: sharepoint-server, navigation, global-navigation

I am creating a site in SharePoint 2013 and I'm having a bit of trouble with the Global Navigation.

Here is what it looks like:

[image]

This dropdown is showing all sub-sites as well as a manual link (QOverview) but it's not showing a Heading (QGlobal).

QCompany is a sub-site of QUBE.  Here is the navigation settings:

QUBE Navigation Config:
[image: QUBE Navigation Config 1]

[image: QUBE Navigation Config 2]

QCompany Navigation Config:
[image]

[image: QCompany Navigation Config 2]

Here is the code in the master page for the navigation:

```
    <!--nav snippet-->
<!--CS: Start Top Navigation Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
<!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" CssClass="ms-core-navigation ms-dialogHidden" BlockElement="True" ID="DeltaTopNavigation">-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" Id="topNavigationDelegate" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource">-->
        <!--MS:<Template_Controls>-->
            <!--MS:<asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ID="topSiteMap" runat="server" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002">-->
            <!--ME:</asp:SiteMapDataSource>-->
        <!--ME:</Template_Controls>-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
    <a name="startNavigation">
    </a>
    <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:AspMenu runat="server"
                   UseSeparateCss="false"
                   AdjustForShowStartingNode="False"
                   StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                   AccessKey="1"
                   SkipLinkText=""
                   CssClass=""
                   EnableViewState="False"
                   MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
                   UseSimpleRendering="False"
                   RenderingMode="List"
                   DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                   ID="TopNavigationMenu">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:AspMenu>-->
    <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
<!--CE: End Top Navigation Snippet-->
<!--end nav snippet-->
```

How can I get the QGlobal links to appear in the QCompany drop-down in Global Navigation?

Answer (score 0):

The sub items under `QGlobal` falls under Level 3. Hence to display those we should set the level property `MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels` to 3.

Your final will look like

```
<!--nav snippet-->
<!--CS: Start Top Navigation Snippet-->
<!--SPM:<%@Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"%>-->
<!--MS:<SharePoint:AjaxDelta runat="server" CssClass="ms-core-navigation ms-dialogHidden" BlockElement="True" ID="DeltaTopNavigation">-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" Id="topNavigationDelegate" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource">-->
        <!--MS:<Template_Controls>-->
            <!--MS:<asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ID="topSiteMap" runat="server" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002">-->
            <!--ME:</asp:SiteMapDataSource>-->
        <!--ME:</Template_Controls>-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
    <a name="startNavigation">
    </a>
    <!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">-->
        <!--MS:<SharePoint:AspMenu runat="server"
                   UseSeparateCss="false"
                   AdjustForShowStartingNode="False"
                   StaticDisplayLevels="2"
                   AccessKey="1"
                   SkipLinkText=""
                   CssClass=""
                   EnableViewState="False"
                   MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="3"
                   UseSimpleRendering="False"
                   RenderingMode="List"
                   DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
                   Orientation="Horizontal"
                   ID="TopNavigationMenu">-->
        <!--ME:</SharePoint:AspMenu>-->
    <!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:AjaxDelta>-->
<!--CE: End Top Navigation Snippet-->
<!--end nav snippet-->
```

Comment: I changed the property as suggested but it still doesn't appear.  I have another dropdown that displays items to the same level as the links within the QGlobal heading and they are shown (although they are all sub-sites not manual links within a heading).

Comment: @Anthony is the heading pointing to a particular URL. Does the current user has permissions on those links?

Comment: @Anthony also try increasing `StaticDisplayLevels` to 3

Comment: The heading was not pointing to a link and the current user is the Site Owner.  At the moment I have just created a QGlobal sub-site and added the links manually (without a heading) and it's working.  I might try a heading with a link just to see if that works too.

Comment: Changing the StaticDisplayLevels from 2 to 3 causes all items under the QCompany item to be displayed as top-level items rather than items.  QCompany must be the last static level displayed; the subsequent sub-sites and links must be dynamic items.

Comment: Adding a link to a heading item makes no difference - it's still not displayed.  The working solution at the moment is QGlobal as a sub-site within QCompany and the manual links have been created in the QGlobal sub-site navigation settings.

Answer (score 0):

QCompany Navigation Config 2
Here is the code in the master page for the navigation:

```
<!--nav snippet-->
```

-->
-->

```
<!--MS:<SharePoint:DelegateControl runat="server" Id="topNavigationDelegate" ControlId="TopNavigationDataSource">-->
    <!--MS:<Template_Controls>-->
        <!--MS:<asp:SiteMapDataSource ShowStartingNode="False" SiteMapProvider="SPNavigationProvider" ID="topSiteMap" runat="server" StartingNodeUrl="sid:1002">-->
        <!--ME:</asp:SiteMapDataSource>-->
    <!--ME:</Template_Controls>-->
<!--ME:</SharePoint:DelegateControl>-->
<a name="startNavigation">
</a>
<!--MS:<asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolderTopNavBar" runat="server">-->
    <!--MS:<SharePoint:AspMenu runat="server"
               UseSeparateCss="false"
               AdjustForShowStartingNode="False"
               StaticDisplayLevels="2"
               AccessKey="1"
               SkipLinkText=""
               CssClass=""
               EnableViewState="False"
               MaximumDynamicDisplayLevels="2"
               UseSimpleRendering="False"
               RenderingMode="List"
               DataSourceID="topSiteMap"
               Orientation="Horizontal"
               ID="TopNavigationMenu">-->
    <!--ME:</SharePoint:AspMenu>-->
<!--ME:</asp:ContentPlaceHolder>-->
```

-->